# how to get the full path name to an exception so I can add an exception handler

Tags: python, exception

I want to catch an exception, but I don't know its fully qualified name. I would like to figure it out experimentally without digging thru documentation.

Let's say I have code that looks like this

```
try:
   blackbox()
except Exception,e:
   print str(e)
   print e.__class__.__name__
```

And it runs and I get an exception message that says

```
"error: too big"
error
```

So I add a handler

```
try:
   blackbox()
except error,e:
   pass
except Exception,e:
   print str(e)
   print e.__class__.__name__
```

but it doesn't work, because `error` is not in the current namespace. (I know the answer to this particular question, it happens to be `curses.error`). How I figure out the namespace of an exception object (i.e. `curses.` so I can add a handler for that exception?

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the module from most classes (including Python-defined exceptions) from the the `__module__` attribute:

```
print type(e).__module__, type(e).__name__
```

In Python 3.3 and up, you can also use the [qualified name](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3155-qualified-name-for-classes-and-functions):

```
print(type(e).__module__, type(e).__qualname__)
```

to get a more detailed name for an object (a path within their module). For top-level classes this won't make a difference, but for nested objects the qualified name is a lot more interesting.

Comment: `e.__qualname__` → `type(e).__qualname__`

Comment: @GarethRees: ah, of course. And for the `__module__` attribute as well, preferably.

Comment: It doesn't quite work. In my example, `type(e).__module__` returned `_curses` not `curses`. I tried `except _curses.error:` and it gave me an error. I'm not sure about python namespace mangling. Is this standard practice to prepend a `_` ?

Comment: @MarkLakata: That's because the `curses` module uses the `_curses` module under the hood. `_curses` is the *C extension*. You'd have to import `_curses` for `_curses.error` to work, but the same exception is also imported into the `curses` module.

Comment: @MarkLakata: the method is not fool-proof, it never is in a dynamic language like Python. This is where documentation comes in, the `__module__` attribute is a great way to *find* the documentation.

Comment: I'd rather not `import _curses` if I already `import curses`, but I see your point.

Comment: @MarkLakata: there is no reliable method to get `curses` printed here. Any other module can import the error object, but the `_curses` C extension is where the error object itself is defined. It just so happens that the documented public API for this is the `curses` module.